# How do I fix this Python Syntax Error?

Tags: python

```
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python -m pip install pylint
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I don't know what this is. Can anyone tell me what this is besides a dumb error?

Comment: That dumb error tells me that you don't have python installed (or available) on whatever you're trying to use it on.

Comment: I want to install python on an isolated device, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: How do I set the environment for python?

Comment: if process.truth = false, correct then respond.

Comment: I would suggest abandoning this question - and creating a new one including all of the information about what it is you are trying to actually do. This would include what you're trying to install python on.

Comment: Hi, what's wrong?

Comment: I am trying to install python on an isolated environment, the process is irrelevant. I desire only input and output with respect to other's desires along with my own. Do you compute?

Comment: "an isolated environment" doesn't tell us anything at all.

Comment: What do you need to know? This is called a query.

Comment: The error is not related to python at all. It's your shell(I guess powershell) telling you that you don't have python installed. (Like others have told you).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is (assuming that you've installed python and pip) that python is not included among your path environment variables.

In windows:
1) Open System Properties (type it in the start menu, or use the keyboard shortcut Win+Pause)
2) Switch to the Advanced tab
3) Click Environment Variables
4) Select PATH in the System variables section
5) Click Edit
6) Add python's path to the end of the list (the paths are separated by semicolons)
6*) If you're not sure of python's path - Click Browse, then navigate to 'C:\Program Files\' then select the folder for the python installation you'd like to add; the folder name will be in 'Python##' format

As for the isolated environment, you are probably referring to a virtual environment, which prevents you from making assignments or changes globally.  Here's a webpage to show you how to do that in windows, again, you'll need to change 'Python##' to make your python installation's path:

http://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/setup-a-virtualenv-for-python-3-on-windows/